# Package in pypi not installable by pip

Tags: python, facebook, pip

Why can't I use

```
$ sudo pip install facebook-python-sdk
```

even with [facebook-python-sdk package in pypi](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/facebook-python-sdk)?

log: http://dpaste.com/hold/589044/

Comment: Adding the error message you get would be really useful if you want accurate answers. Without knowing the problem, it's hard to find a solution.

Comment: Thanks, it looks like, as the only link on the PyPI page leads to the github page, pip gets it and tries to find a download link on it, at which it failed. I'd suggest you to use @zeekay solution to install it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what's going on there, but you can use `pip` to install from the github repo:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/facebook/python-sdk.git\#egg=facebook-python-sdk
```

I usually use `pip install -e` which makes pip symlink the package for you, so you can edit the repo, update it etc, and get the latest changes without having to pip install again.

Comment: It not seems to be 'clean', because installs in the current dir.
Is there any way to install from git inside the 'dist-packages'?

Comment: You can still `python setup.py install` the package normally if you want to.

Comment: hey, @zVictor, you can avoid using the -e flag:
`pip install git+https://github.com/facebook/python-sdk.git#egg=facebook-python-sdk`

Comment: This is giving me an error "Cannot find command 'git'". what should I do? help me.

Comment: Make sure git is installed and available in your `PATH`.